# Multiple selects in laravel 6.0

Tags: php, laravel

0, I have this code that works perfectly

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as gold, cat_cliente'))->where('cat_cliente', '=','Gold')
   ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
   ->get();
```

I want to make another select but with another condition, I tried with this but doesn't work

```
$data = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as gold, cat_cliente'))->where('cat_cliente', '=','Gold')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as silver, cat_cliente'))->where('cat_cliente', '=','Silver')
   ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
   ->get();
```

Can somebody help me?

Comment: Is their a particular reason you are not using `Eloquent` relationships? It is one of the main advantages of using the Larvel framework? (https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent)

Comment: What error are you getting (if any)? Or what is the expected output vs the the one are getting?

Comment: I dont know how to use eloquent at all... I found this method and it works but only with one Select, didn't send error only dont print the result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Group By `cat_cliente`, this will count gold, count silver..., in each records.

```php
DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->select(DB::raw('count(incidencias.id) as count'), cat_cliente)
   ->whereIn('cat_cliente', ['Gold', 'Silver'])
   ->groupBy('cat_cliente')
   ->get();
```

output =>

```
-----------------
 count | cat_cliente
------------------
   10  | Gold
------------------
    3  | Siliver
-----------------
```

You want to put them in one record, I think you can get it out and display it by loop.
However, if you really want to get it in query, try this:

```php
$gold_query = DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->where('cat_cliente', 'Gold')
   ->selectRaw('COUNT(incidencias.id) AS gold', '0 AS silver');

$silver_query =  DB::table('incidencias')
   ->join('clientes_incid', 'clientes_incid.rif', '=', 'incidencias.rif')
   ->where('cat_cliente', 'Silver')
   ->selectRaw('0 AS gold, count(incidencias.id) AS silver');

$gold_silver = $gold_query->unionAll($silver_query);

DB::table(DB::raw("({$gold_silver->toSql()}) AS gs"))
          ->mergeBindings($gold_silver)
          ->selectRaw('SUM(gold) AS gold, SUM(silver) AS silver')
          ->get()
```

Output =>

```
----------------
 gold | silver | 
-----------------
   10  | 3    |
----------------
```

Comment: ok.. that works but how could I separate it silver and gold to write it in a different table? thanks a lot!!

Comment: @Oscar What do u means in different table, can u give me an example?

Comment: I want to write it gold as case1 and silver as case2 and in your function you put only as count, in this way I cant separate the count

Comment: @Oscar If it helps u, plz accept the answer or upvote it.

Comment: Sorry I'm new in this forum... I think that i did it.. if I have to do another think to accept your answer let me know.. thank you so much